# How can i get the correct height immediately after use masonry?

Tags: ios, objective-c

i make Constraints like this

> ```
>     [countDownLabel mas_makeConstraints:^(MASConstraintMaker *make) {
>         make.left.equalTo(countDownIcon.mas_right).offset(5);
>         make.right.equalTo(headAlertView).offset(-20);
>         make.top.equalTo(headAlertView).offset(5);
>         make.height.mas_greaterThanOrEqualTo(15);
>     }];
> ```

and i wanna get label's height like this:

> ```
> [self.view layoutIfNeeded];
>
> NSLog(@"height%f", countDownLabel.height);
>
> dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(0.1 * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
>     NSLog(@"dispatch_after height%f", countDownLabel.height);
> });
> ```

but i can't get the correct height immediately;

Print result as follows

> height16.000000
>
> dispatch_after height31.500000

How can i get the correct height immediately after use masonry?

Answer (score 0):

This is because you may get height of view before layout is determined.
Get height in viewDidLayoutSubviews().

Comment: is there any way get height not in viewDidLayoutSubviews()?